# BC Dimension Combinations

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-business-central

I'm using Business Central in the Cloud, and I have a data structure with nested dimensions (I don't know a better term for it).  There's Dimensions A, B, and C. Each dimension has a full list, but only some of the entries in Dimension B are valid for a given value of Dimension A.  Likewise, only a subset of Dimension C is valid for a given value of Dimension B.  I've been tasked with using Power BI to create a report that shows which values for C are allowed for each B, and likewise for B and A.  I can't find a table, page, web service, or API that shows that info.  How would I go about retrieving it?

Comment: Are you talking about a Snowflake Schema? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema  Or are there Many-to-Many relationships between the dimensions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/relationships-many-to-many#relate-many-to-many-dimensions

Comment: This is specifically relating to Dimensions as they are defined in Business Central.  A better example would be a hierarchy like Department > Team > Role

Comment: If the relationships are 1-to-many then just import the three tables and create relationships in Power BI.  Filters automatically flow across relationships.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-create-and-manage-relationships

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  I'm talking about Dimensions as they are used in Business Central, not Dimension tables.

Another example:  For the Accounts Payable GL Account, there might be a dimension for Taxes, one for OpEx and a third for Interest Expense.  Each of those dimensions is linked to the Vendor Dimension, but only certain vendors are allowed for each.

Comment: Another Example: Each value of the State dimension has certain acceptable values of the County dimension, which has certain acceptable values of the City dimension.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default API available to retrieve the Dimension Combinations.

You will have to create your own API by [extending Business Central](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-dev-overview).

The data your are looking for can be found in the following tables:

- `Dimension Combination` (table 350)
- `Dimension Value Combination` (table 351)